# VM guest not accessible from Host (with running VPN Client)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I have configured my guest VM as described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/293817/503589

Unfortunately I cannot connect to the guest via IP or "localhost", if the Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client is connected on the host (Windows 7).
It works as long as I am not connected with the Cisco VPN AnyConnect Client on the host.

My requirements are the following:

- the host should be able to access the guest with it's static IP, whether I am connected to host VPN or not.
- I am working remote (WLAN) or in the office (LAN). In the office it's working, because I have no Cisco VPN Client connected.
- guest can access the internet
- I can move my laptop from network to network (e.g. from home to office to coffeeshop) without worrying about securing or reconfiguring the vm

What I also already tried and what didn't work:

- NAT
- Bridged

Answer (score 1):

The Cisco VPN client is likely configured for full tunneling. Meaning all traffic is routed through the VPN interface. This is why you are unable to reach other hosts on your LAN.

You might be able to request a split-tunneled profile from your Network team, but it may go against company policy.